# Working with devices in Windows using Blazor (c# + webassembly)

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm learning Blazor (web host using c# and webassembly).

My question 1 is: Is there any way I can show Device Manager on the client side web?

If so question 2 is: Can I connect to devices on COM ports using serial connection?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Most likely: No and No. You can google what privileges an (installed) PWA can have. Beyond that, look at Blazor Mobile Bindings or just Xamarin. But the COM port is usually off limits.

Comment: When you found something useful you can post a self-answer below.

Comment: Since Chrome 89 it is possible to access serial ports from the browser, see https://web.dev/serial
So it may be possible to access it with Blazor WebAssembly, I just never tried it to confirm for you